# Permission to delete from a directory

Tags: c#, .net, security

I am writing code that checks for the permission to write to and delete from certain directories. The first is fairly easy. To whit:

```
FileIOPermission writePermit = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, _ArchiveHome);
writePermit.Demand();
```

But, how do I do the same for permission to delete from a given directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Write property mutually means you can delete
[msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermissionaccess(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The write permit allows you to modify files as in, deleting, modifying, creating, adding.